# Show the elements of a specific table row when button is clicked inside that table row

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have a database with folder paths in index.php. The user then selects one or more paths to run which are then queried to search.php. Each row has its respected button, when the button is clicked the path gets send to a series of functions (ajax.php, ajax2.php, ajax3.php) and at the end a report is saved in a folder. pdf_report.php should then display the report inside the row.

My issue is when any button is clicked, the report always shows up in the first row and not in the row clicked on. The following is my code:

**search.php**

```
      <?php
        ...
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $field1name = $row["test_id"];
            $field2name = $row["path"];
            $field3name = $row["video1_path"];
            $field4name = $row["video2_path"];
            $field5name = $row["video3_path"];
            $field6name = $row["video4_path"];

          echo "<tr>
                  <td> ".$field1name." </td>
                  <td> ".$field2name." </td>
                  <td> ".$field3name." </td>
                  <td> ".$field4name." </td>
                  <td> ".$field5name." </td>
                  <td> ".$field6name." </td>

                  <td><div>
                        <button class='edit' id='" . $row['test_id'] . "'>Run</button>
                      </div></td>


                  <td><div id='result'>
                    <p></p>
                  </div></td>

                </tr>";
        }
      }else {
        echo '<span style="color:#ff0000;text-align:center;">No Test ID Selected!</span>';
      }
    }


    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
  ?>
  </table>
</div><br>

<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
<table id=test_data>
  <tr>
    <th>Progress</th>
    <th>Progress Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div><progress id='progBar' value='0' max='100'></progress></div></td>
    <td><div><p id='progress-text'></p></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>


<!--Uses jquery to run 3 scripts and displays it in a progress bar-->
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
  //set cookie value to 'path'
  var fcookie='mycookie';
  var test_id = $(this).attr('id');
  if(test_id) {
    var path = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:nth-child(2)").text()};

  document.cookie='fcookie='+path;

    //Start of 1st script
      $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type:"POST",
        success: function(data) {
          //alert("File 1 Completed")

            $("#progress-text").text("Executing file 1");
            $('#progBar').val(25);

            //Start of 2nd script
            $.ajax({
              url: "ajax2.php",
              type:"POST",
                success: function(data2) {
                  //alert("File 2 Completed")
                  $("#progress-text").text("Executing file 2");
                  $('#progBar').val(50);

                  //Start of 3rd script
                  $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax3.php",
                    type:"POST",
                      success: function(data2) {
                        //alert("File 2 Completed")
                         $("#progress-text").text("Complete");
                         $('#progBar').val(100);


                        //Loads the report
                         $("#result").load("pdf_report.php");

                      }
                  })
                }
            })
          }
    })
    return false;
   //});
});



</script>
```

I am new to php and jquery. Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is with the way that you load the report, you load it into the <div id='result'> which should be unique! You can add the id of the row in the name or simply use jquery to find the 8th <td>.

Comment: Hi, do you mind helping me a bit further. Do you mean this? <td><div class='result' id='" . $row['test_id'] . "'>
                    <p></p>
                  </div></td>

Comment: I will write an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change:

```
//Loads the report
$("#result").load("pdf_report.php");
```

By:

```
//Loads the report
$(this).closest('tr').find("td:nth-child(8) div").load("pdf_report.php");
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out but it does not seem to be working. what should i edit in side the <td> tags.   <td><div id= '". row['test_id'] . "'><p></p></div></td>?

Comment: I had to add this at the beginning   var $this = $(this); before the first $.ajax and then it will look like this  $this.closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(8)").load("pdf_report.php"); . There was a step missing

Comment: Dont forget to put a thumbs up :)